# Android Webview Repaint Delay (lag) upon orientation change

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am developing a phonegap application which is locked into landscape.
As it currently stands if the app is reopened whilst the device is in portrait Android opens the app as if it was portrait (thus making the webpage the incorrect size - half renders), then releases its mistake then judders to the correct orientation before re-rendering.

Whilst this issue is not permanent it is very undesirable.

```css
.closed {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.open {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.app {
  width: 360px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.open2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  background: green;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="closed">
  Phone in landscape, with device rotation locked so it shows apps and the like in portrait.
</div>

<div class="open">
  <div class="app">
    Once the app is opened it renders like this for around a second until the device catches up and performs the full rotation and repaint.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="open2">
  After the split second the device correctly rotates (the device does a rotation animation), then the app is correctly sized.
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Jshthornton/pen/emzWYO

Comment: have you set preference settings in config.xml to lock orientation?

Comment: @AAhad I have indeed. The intention is to have it locked in landscape, and that works fine. However it is just the rerendering upon the app opening from a prior portrait state.

Comment: I think , you verify your css. There would be some CSS issues that is eating the rendering frames. If possible , run the app without heavy css ..or plain app and see the differences.

Comment: @AAhad I removed everything last bit of CSS and it is still performing the same way.

Comment: @AAhad Additionally, I have also disabled all JS on the page and am left with only HTML which does the same.
This issue can be replicated on an Android device running 4.4.2, in the emulator, locking it into landscape, and opening it from a portrait view.

Comment: okay, if possible to share the html code, so that I can run and test? Thanks

Comment: @AAhad https://gist.github.com/jshthornton/31837f7ab20223371120

Comment: It works fine to me on device v4.2.2. it opens app in portrait in whatever mode i hold the device... now seeing on emulator...may be emulators are slow and so are taking some leg time

Comment: @AAhad try locking the orientation to landscape in the config.xml, then hold the device in landscape, open the app, close the app, then reopen it. It appears to be the action of closing the app which causes the sizing issue, not the opening of the app.

Comment: yes its happening on emulator only

Comment: @AAhad yeah, I can not get it to replicate on a device, but I have a client confirming it is doing it on two physical devices.

Comment: Ok, I am doing something, if succeeded will update :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility which you can try.

There is `window resize` **event** that gets fired on **device/emulator rotate**. Here I guess if you try to fix the `width & height` (via css media queries for multiple devices), would **might** work out.

```
window.onresize = function(){    
     console.log("window.onresize::Height:"+ window.innerHeight + " Width:" + window.innerWidth); 
}
```

Plus also listen to the **resume** event and re-apply the css queries.

```
var app = {
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', this.onDeviceResume, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    onDeviceResume: function() {
         console.log("onDeviceResume....");
         var windowHeight = 0, windowWidth = 0;
         if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
             windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
             windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
          }
      console.log("Resume: Height:"+ window.innerHeight + " innerWidth:" + window.innerWidth); 
    } 
};
```

If you notice, currently the `width & height` is showing one value on `resume` and after `resize` call it applies updated sizes/values. So I guess here something could be done.

Comment: Cheers. I will take a look into it soon and give you an update.